# Problems with \textsc for single glyph

Tags: fonts, small-caps

Is there a way (simple or otherwise) to import a single character from another font under specific characters, or otherwise alter the character?

I'm using the very attractive Garamond font from [here](http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/garamond/), but there is a slight problem - when using `\ae{}` with `\textsc{}`, the font defaults to lower case.

A MWE can be gained by downloading the package from the website mentioned, then using this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{garamond}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ggm}\normalfont

\begin{document}

\garamond
Normal ligature: \ae{}

Capital ligature: \AE{}

Small Caps: \textsc{\AE{}, \ae{}, Isch\ae{}mia}
\end{document}
```

The result is shown in the following figure (I also did it without Garamond, to be sure it wasn't just a problem with my code).

[image: MWE Result]

Using the provided font sfd files, FontForge, and most of the instructions given [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide/fontinstallationguide.pdf), I have been able to generate a font that corrects the problem, but it loses most of the hanging fonts and whatnot, or rather it utilises them sporadically.

Does anyone know how to point LaTeX to use a different glyph, either a modified version of the standard capital or the glyph from the self-built version of the font?

Comment: this won't exactly answer your question, but solve your original problem: there's better Garamonds around, even in the TeX world. Try the `ebgaramond` package, for example, which will give you a proper SC `ae`, and better overall results as well.

Comment: Thanks Nils L - that was going to be my solution if the solution below hadn't worked. If I come across any other problems, though, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The small caps font has only the 26 unaccented letters realized as small caps. So much work would be needed for getting all the characters. If all you need is æ, do the following steps.

1. run `vftovp ggmrc8t.vf > ggmrc8t.vpl`
2. open the resulting `ggmrc8t.vpl` file with a text editor.
3. find the entry starting with `CHARACTER O 346` and change it to read

   ```
   (CHARACTER O 346
      (CHARWD R 0.8552)
      (CHARHT R 0.5452)
      (CHARDP R 0.016)
      (COMMENT
         (KRN C v R 0.001)
         (KRN C y R 0.001)
         (KRN O 375 R 0.001)
         (KRN O 270 R 0.001)
         (KRN O 47 R -0.003)
         (KRN C t R 0.002)
         (KRN C w R -0.005)
         (KRN C x R -0.007)
         (KRN C V R -0.076)
         (KRN O 265 R 0.002)
         )
      (MAP
         (SELECTFONT D 1)
         (SETCHAR O 306)
         )
      )
   ```
4. run vftovp `ggmrc8t.vpl` and replace the corresponding `tfm` and `vf` file with the new ones.

What I did is mapping the character to the Æ in reduced size and computing new height and width by scaling at 80% the dimensions of the Æ character. However, trying other characters will fail and need other similar massaging.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I'd managed to waste 3 days trying to figure it out!

Comment: @PhilG Actually this is a simplistic solution: there are many kerning pairs involving æ and I didn't approach the problem. Go to EB Garamond. `;-)`