# Installing EBGaramond for pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive, ebgaramond

I made a foolish choice to play around with fonts a few days ago, and haven't escaped since. After getting very kind and useful help [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137454/problems-with-textsc-for-single-glyph) yesterday, I decided to follow the advice given, and change to use EBGaramond from the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ebgaramond/). This, however, has proved problematic.

I tried to follow the instructions given [here](http://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) as best I could - below is the sequence of events, using the following code as a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}
Testing\ldots{}
\end{document}
```

First of all, I used `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` to determine obtain the value of `/usr/local/share/texmf`, to which I moved the unzipped `ebgaramond` folder (I had to use `sudo mv` to do so). I then applied `sudo texhash`, which gave the output:

```
texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEMAIN... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

and then `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=EBGaramond.map`, which produced

```
updmap: resetting $HOME value (was /home/philip) to root's actual home (/root).
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
Creating new config file /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
pxdvi output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap"

ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
    EBGaramond.map (in /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)

    Did you run mktexlsr?

    You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
  --syncwithtrees.
```

On the basis of that output, I ran `sudo mktexlsr`, followed by `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=EBGaramond.map`.

This, however, produced an error when I ran pdfLaTeX, saying ebgaramond.sty could not be found. I thus then moved `ebgaramond` to `~/texmf/tex/latex/`, and reran `sudo texhash`. Now, however, the compilation fails with the error

```
! I can't find file `EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-t1'.
```

I did try putting in `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{ebgaramond}`, but that threw up another series of errors, and I'd really rather not go down the XeTeX route.

I'll admit, I have been lurching through the problems, but can anyone please give me some tips on this? The phrasing in the README suggests it's a simple process, but I'm still having troubles.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: you don't need `fontspec` or the commands that follow with `ebgaramond` package. You don't need the `fontenc` package either. Try this, Type in your terminal `tlmgr show ebgaramond` and see if it's installed. If not, it's always a good idea to try to copy the whole folder and its contents (assuming it is unzipped of course) into say `texmf-dist/tex/latex` , although the local directory is recommended most of the times, there are times when you have no option but to use the `texmf` directory like you just did.

Comment: A distribution like Ubuntu is meant to simplify things, not to complicate them. Install the full TUG TeX Live rather than the Debian one; it just requires a (not really so) complicated session and you'll have EB Garamond out of the box (and not only that).

Comment: Exactly! and then install TeX Live by `./install-tl --gui wizard` (if a message says `Cannot load Tk` then `sudo apt-get install perl-tk`. Remember either way (whether in the wizard mode or text mode) to edit the folder where you want it. Unless the `/usr` folder has enough space, I suggest you to use another directory. Once the installation finishes, remember to copy the last lines that will say something like  `Most importantly, add /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY` to your PATH for current and future sessions. Copy that Then open `.bashrc` and add `PATH=/PATH/TO/DIRECTORY:$PATH`, save and restart.

Comment: Thanks to both for the advice - I did follow it, and after an installation plagued with a dodgy internet connection, I managed to install it without much hassle. As a slight word of warning: I did have a small problem with one of the files, but the fix is presented http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135781/are-itemize-and-ebgaramond-compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by uninstalling the Ubuntu package, and installing the full package directly. Slight problem with installation solved according to [Are itemize and EBGaramond compatible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135781/are-itemize-and-ebgaramond-compatible)