# Installing EB Garamond (miktex lua) encore encore

Tags: fonts, miktex, luatex, ebgaramond

There are many related questions and answers. I looked at [Installing EB Garamond for pdfLaTeX (encore)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146894/installing-eb-garamond-for-pdflatex-encore) and tried the lua answer there. `lualatex` from a freshly instlled Miktex on this MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}

The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog. 0123456789 

\emph{Try italics.} \\
{\bfseries Try bold face} \\
{\scshape Try small caps} \\

\end{document}
```

produces

```
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: C:\Users\eb\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
package repository: http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 8a9d030e8c8fa3aaa59a4f1bbb445ea5
going to download 8096508 bytes
going to install 181 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/tipa.tar.lzma...
8096508 bytes, 765.27 KB/Sec
extracting files from tipa.tar.lzma...
======================================================================

(C:/Users/eb/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9//tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def(save: C:/Users
/eb/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmromanslant10-regul
ar.lua)(save: C:/Users/eb/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/ot
f/lmromanslant10-regular.luc)(save: C:/Users/eb/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-
cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-italic.lua)(save: C:/Users/eb/AppData/Local/Mi
KTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-italic.luc)(save: C:/Users/eb/
AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-bold.lua)(save
: C:/Users/eb/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-
bold.luc) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmss.fd")(save:
 C:/Users/eb/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmsans10-re
gular.lua)(save: C:/Users/eb/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts
/otf/lmsans10-regular.luc))
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty"
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty")
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty"
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty")
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/00miktex/graphics.cfg")
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def"
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty")
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty"
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.lua))))))
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg")))
luaotfload | cache : No lookup cache, creating empty.
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated; reason: "unresolved font name: 'ebgaramond12
'"
luaotfload | db : Font index saved

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "EBGaramond12" cannot be found.
```

The Miktex package manager says ebgaramond is there.

The fontspec documentation is pretty dense.

I've looked at http://docs.miktex.org/manual/advanced.html#psfonts, to no avail.I can't examine `updmap.cfg` because windows 7 search doesn't find it and I don't know where to look by hand.

Edit: As per @UlrikeFischer comment:

```
eb@7J8B8W1 ~
$  luaotfload-tool -u -vv
...
luaotfload | util : Task completed successfully

eb@7J8B8W1 ~
$  luaotfload-tool --alias=luaotfload-tool --find="ebgaramond"
luaotfload | resolve : Cannot find "ebgaramond".
```

**Edit: Progress!** `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` works with `pdflatex`. (The bold face doesn't, but according to a comment elsewhere by @egreg I shouldn't want it anyway.)

Perhaps I should move my whole project from luatex to pdftex.

Comment: Do lualatex works if you use `\setmainfont{Arial}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, Arial works. (So does arial.)

Comment: Does `\setmainfont{EB Garamond 12}` work?

Comment: @cfr No. The 12 doesn't help.

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed the OpenType version of EB Garamond?

Comment: I've only installed what came automatically with miktex.

Comment: Can you tell which fonts were installed as part of MikTeX's `ebgaramond` package? In particular, do you have only the type1 fonts (`pfb` files) or do you have opentype (`otf`) as well?

Comment: @cfr The Miktex package manager lists files EBGaramond12-Italic.otf and 12-Regular.otf, and .pfb files with the same names.

Comment: The name of your lua cache is odd. Is your miktex up-to-date? Did you run update with the user and admin update manager? Does the cache file contains an entry for ebgaramond?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just uninstalled miktex and reinstalled the latest version. I get essentially the same error message - newer version in the edited question.

Comment: Can you try compiling a file which loads `ebgaramond` using pdfTeX? If MiKTeX can't find the type1 versions either, that might suggest that the package just didn't get installed properly at all.

Comment: Update on a command line the luaotfload database (`luaotfload-tool -u -vv`) (if it hangs somewhere you will have to blacklist the fonts). Then check with `luaotfload-tool --alias=luaotfload-tool  --find="ebgaramond"` if the font is found.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer lua can't find the font - see edited question

Comment: @cfr I don't know how to tell pdftex to try ebgaramond. Searches on this site haven't helped me yet. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138718/installing-ebgaramond-for-pdflatex is for ubuntu.

Comment: What command line did you use?  Are you sure you are using miktex there? If you want to use the font with pdflatex: `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` should work directly (naturally without fontspec + setmainfont).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Works with pdftex - question edited to say so.

Comment: It isn't that the bold face doesn't work. EB Garamond does not have a bold face by design.

Comment: @cfr I understand that - it's the essence of egreg's design comment.

Comment: @cfr If you post "use pdflatex instead of lua" as an answer I'll accept it since it serves my purpose. I'll leave the question up since others may need a lua solution.

Comment: @EthanBolker OK. I've posted an answer as requested. Sorry not to help with the lua case - I don't use MiKTeX, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 6):

Provided the type1 fonts have been correctly installed by the package manager, one option may be to use pdfLaTeX for compilation:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}

  \centering
  The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog.\\
  0123456789\\
  \emph{Try italics.}\\
  {\scshape Try small caps.}

\end{document}
```

[image: EB Garamond type1]

I have omitted the bold test since EB Garamond lacks a bold face by design.

Comment: As per the discussion at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/answers-that-solve-the-problem-without-answering-the-question?cb=1 I'm unaccepting this answer - but leaving the upvote and hoping for upvotes from others.

Comment: @EthanBolker As a participant in that discussion, that seems good to me ;). I hope some Lua guru will happen along to actually answer the question!